# gMap JSON string?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-gmap

I have the following html;

```
    <div class="event-details-container">
<div class="event-details">
<div class="adress">My adress</div>
<div class="arranger">My arranger</div>
<div class="title">My title</div>
<div class="date">My date</div>
</div>
<div class="event-details">
<div class="adress">My adress 2</div>
<div class="arranger">My arranger 2</div>
<div class="title">My title 2</div>
<div class="date">My date 2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And i have the following JS:

```
    var myMarkers = "";
$('.event-details-container .event-details').each(function (index) {
    myMarkers += "{ address: " + $(this).children(".adress").text() + ", html: " + "<div style='font-siz:14px;font-weight:bold'>" + $(this).children(".title").text() + "</div>" + $(this).children(".date").text() + "<br/>" + $(this).children(".arranger").text() + "<br/>" + $(this).children(".adress").text() + "},";
});

$(".google-map").gMap({ markers: [myMarkers.slice(0, -1)],
    address: "Washington DC, US",
    zoom: 6
});
```

The JS above is based on http://gmap.nurtext.de/ (a plugin for jQuery).
But the above code does not work - the map shows, but no markers - so there must be something wrong with the Json "string" i am putting together - but what?

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but `address` is misspelled.

Comment: can you host a fiddle please?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to create an actual object, not a string representation? If you want to go the string route, you need to generate valid JSON; double quotes around the variable names and non-numeric values (e.g. { "address" : "some address", ... } )

Comment: @Brian Roach: Could you show an example of how you would do it if it was object based?
zzzz: fiddle?
K ballo: I know ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm *not* a javascript guy ... so someone may need to clean this up a bit.

Looking at the docs for the plugin, you need to supply an object containing:

a string named `address`

a number named `zoom`

an array named `markers` which holds objects containing

- a string named `address`

  a string named `html`.

```
var myMarkers = [];
$('.event-details-container .event-details').each(function (index) {
    var myHtml = "<div style='font-siz:14px;font-weight:bold'>" + 
              $(this).children(".title").text() + "</div>" + 
              $(this).children(".date").text() + "<br/>" + 
              $(this).children(".arranger").text() + "<br/>" + 
              $(this).children(".adress").text();

    myMarkers.push({ address: $(this).children(".adress").text(), html : myHtml}); 
});

var myObj = { address : "Washington, DC", zoom : 6, markers : myMarkers };

$(".google-map").gMap(myObj);
```

(I broke things out a bit so you could get a handle on what's going on)